# Convert xml file to csv in shell script?

Tags: xml, linux, shell, csv

I'm trying to convert a xml file to a csv file. I have an input xml file like this:

```
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" >START</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="DateTime" >2013-01-15T21:30:42</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" ></Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" >Start 'suite8'</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" >Test 'suite8' started</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" ></Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
<Row/>
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" >START_TEST_CASE</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="DateTime" >2013-01-15T21:30:42</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" ></Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" >Start 'case1'</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" >Test Case 'case1' started</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data Type="String" >case1</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
```

I'm interested in the bits between the tags `<Data Type="String" >` and `</Data>`. Also, a new line should be started when the tag `<Row>` appears.

The output csv file I want should look like this:

```
START,2013-01-15T21:30:42,,Test 'suite8' started 

START_TEST_CASE,2013-01-15T21:30:42,,Start 'case1',Test Case 'case1' started,case1
```

I hope this is clear enough, any help is greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is a perl or python script which will be just a few lines but will be much more robust and faster to write than any shell/grep/sed/awk one might be able to get to work. Are you open to such an option?

Comment: You do realise that your desired output isn't actually well-formed CSV?  The numbers of "columns" between your rows differ....

Comment: You should use an XML parser.

Comment: sds: I'm open to other options, but I know even less in perl or python script. I'm a newbie :(

Comment: tink: I realised it now, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at xslt stylesheets and the `xsltproc` command. If it is just converting unconditionally all data to rows with comma separated values from the cell tags it's a relatively simple stylesheet.

A quick search yielded this: [XML to CSV Using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365312/xml-to-csv-using-xslt)
With a few adaptations to your xml it should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML with Bash has been addressed here before:

[How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash)

That said it seems like a painful way to live.

Comment: It looks very painful indeed, aarrgghh! :)