# Parse specific XML to CSV format

Tags: xml, bash

How can I, using some bash/shell script, transform this input

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<runJobReturn xmlns="http://xml.org" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.org" xsi:type="ns1:runJobReturn">
    <ns1:item xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOf_xsd_string">
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">15-02-2013</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">Benjamin</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">MASSY</ns1:item>
    </ns1:item>
    <ns1:item xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOf_xsd_string">
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">15-02-2013</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">Ronald</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">MASSY</ns1:item>
    </ns1:item>
    <ns1:item xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOf_xsd_string">
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">15-02-2013</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">Zachary</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">MASSY</ns1:item>
    </ns1:item>
    <ns1:item xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOf_xsd_string">
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">12</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">13</ns1:item>
    </ns1:item>
    <ns1:item xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOf_xsd_string">
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">12</ns1:item>
        <ns1:item xsi:type="xsd:string">13</ns1:item>
    </ns1:item>
</runJobReturn>
</soapenv:Body>
```

To this output:

```
15-02-2013|Benjamin|MASSY
15-02-2013|Ronald|MASSY
15-02-2013|Zachary|MASSY
12|13
12|13
```

Input is from curl. I've tried to use sed :
echo $INP | tr -d "\n" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>/\n/g'
but in output remains multiply new lines between values

Comment: Don't use regex/sed/awk for processing xml. And [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317053/how-should-i-go-about-converting-xml-into-csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't use [regex to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). It's just as easy to run XSLT in bash.

I would recommend running either running the Java version of [Saxon-HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE) from the [command line](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.xml) (XSLT 2.0) or running [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (XSLT 1.0).

Examples:

**XSLT 2.0** (Saxon)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.org">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:runJobReturn/ns1:item">
        <xsl:value-of select="ns1:item" separator="|"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (XMLStarlet, Saxon, Xalan, etc.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.org">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:runJobReturn/ns1:item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:item"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:item">
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Either one of these stylesheets, applied to your input XML, will produce the output you wanted:

```
15-02-2013|Benjamin|MASSY
15-02-2013|Ronald|MASSY
15-02-2013|Zachary|MASSY
12|13
12|13
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick awk one-liner:

```
echo $INP |awk -F '[<>]' '$2 ~ "xsd:string" {row = row "|" $3} $2 == "/ns1:item" {print substr(row, 2) ; row = ""}'
```